# How to specify the allowed attachment file types for Action Text in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, actiontext

I want to specify my ActionText to only allow image file types.
I tried this in my model rb file:

```
has_rich_text :content, attachments: { content_type: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'] }
```

but I get this error:

```
unknown keyword: :attachments
```

Answer (score 4):

On the front end you can work directly with *Trix*:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"

const allowedImageTypes = ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"]

document.addEventListener("trix-file-accept", e => {
  if (allowedImageTypes.includes(e.file.type)) {
    console.log("attach");
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("reject");
    // TODO: show useful notification
  }
})
```

*https://github.com/basecamp/trix#storing-attached-files*

---

For the server side validations you have to dig into [ActionText::RichText](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4/actiontext/app/models/action_text/rich_text.rb) model to get to the attachments:

```rb
ALLOWED_IMAGE_TYPES = %w[image/png image/jpg image/jpeg image/gif]

has_rich_text :content

validate do
  content.body.attachables.each do |attachment|
    unless ALLOWED_IMAGE_TYPES.include? attachment.content_type
      errors.add(:content, "includes unsupported image type")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

has_rich_text does not have attachments option.

You have to use has_one_attached for image attachments. These attached images can be easily referred in action text using sgid. [Reference](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#rendering-attachments)

```
has_many_attached :photos
```

For validation on content type:

```
validates :photos, attached: true, content_type: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg']
```

For referencing the sgid (Signed GlobalID) :

```
photo.to_signed_global_id.to_s # here photo is one photo object
```